# What data is submitted when using a <select> element?

Tags: html, forms, html-select

I have the following `<select>` in a contact form.
Is "type" going to be passed to *mail.php* as the `<option>` `value` or as the text associated with it?

```
<select name="type" size="1">
    <option value="1">Select A Category</option>
    <option value="2">Questions</option>
    <option value="3">Report Problems</option>
    <option value="4">Suggestion</option>
    <option value="5">Other</option>
    <option value="6">Website Problem</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is the `value` attribute of the `option`

Comment: So, if I were to reformat the option statements to read like "<option value="Questions"></option>" I'd get the text?

Comment: That will work, but the options in the list will be empty. If you format them like `<option>Text</option>`, the "Text" will be submitted because there is no `value` attribute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add each one look like this

```
<option value="Questions">Questions</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute of an `<option>` element is submitted.
If that attribute is missing, the text content of the element is submitted instead.

See [`<option>` attributes @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes):

> **`value`**
>   The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.

Also see [The `option` element @ w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-option-element.html#attr-option-value):

> The `value` attribute provides a value for element. The value of an `option` element is the value of the `value` attribute, if there is one, or the `textContent` of the element, if there isn't.